# Java8 Stream as a whole maps to a Function

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if there's a better way to rewrite the groupA method with lambda as part of the chaining operations ?

```
public class Id {
    private final int value;
    public Id(int value) {
       this.value = value;
    }

    public int value() {
       return value;
    }
}

public class Ids implements Iterable<Id> { 
   private final List<Id> ids;

   private Ids(List<Id> ids) {
      this.ids = ids;
   }

   public static Ids of(List<Id> ids) {
      return new Ids(ids);
   }

   public Ids groupA() {
      return Ids.of(ids.stream()
                       .filter(id -> id.value() > 5)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<Id> iterator() {
      return ids.iterator();
   }
}
```

Basically I want to do something like

```
ids.stream()
   .filter(id -> id % 10 > 5)
   .collect(Collectiors.toList())
   .andThen(Ids::of);
```

And wonder if that's possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.  You can either just do the straightforward

```
Ids.of(ids.stream()
   .filter(id -> id % 10 > 5)
   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

or you could add it to the collector:

```
ids.stream()
   .filter(id -> id % 10 > 5)
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Ids::of))
```

Comment: when I do option2 which is the one that uses collectingAndThen that the compiler explains having problem resolving method 'of'

Comment: @peter what is the exact error?  It looks like the types aren't quite right, since you can't do `id % 10` with `id` of type `Id`.

Comment: Though the static method is not necessary in this context. Here, `Ids::of` could be replaced by `Ids::new`. Besides that, @peter what’s wrong with the original approach?

Comment: @peter I don't get that error when I actually plug this into a compiler.  http://ideone.com/pr1ryb

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry it works...I forget to take out the outtermost Ids.of function...but thanks !!!

Comment: @Holger nothing wrong with the original approach...just looking for alternatives

Comment: @LouisWasserman do these two approaches perform mostly the same ?

Comment: @peter the first one performs a tiny bit better, since you're not allocating the `Collector` or the lambda.  The JIT might be able to optimize that away, but if it doesn't improve readability what's the point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101616/discussion-between-peter-and-louis-wasserman).

Answer (score 2):

In my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library there's a shortcut method [`toListAndThen`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#toListAndThen-java.util.function.Function-) which makes this looking more fluent:

```
StreamEx.of(ids)
  .filter(id -> id % 10 > 5)
  .toListAndThen(Ids::of);
```